# Asynchronous download issue with UITableView & ASIHTTP

Tags: iphone, uitableview, asynchronous, asihttprequest

I try to load some image on my UITableView with ASIHTTP but I have some problems. First of all I read an xml file (with tbxml) and I save title, image path and description in a dictionary and then in an array, for parsing I use this code:

```
- (void)loadUnknownXML {    
    // Load and parse the books.xml file
    tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxx.com"]];

    // If TBXML found a root node, process element and iterate all children
    if (tbxml.rootXMLElement){
        [self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
    }
}

- (void) traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element {

    TBXMLElement *child = element->firstChild;
    TBXMLElement *items = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:child];

    do{
        if (items->firstChild) {

            TBXMLElement *titolo = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:items];
            TBXMLElement *descrizione = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"description" parentElement:items];
            //NSLog(@"Titolo: %@ \n Descrizione: %@",[TBXML textForElement:titolo],[TBXML textForElement:descrizione]);

            self.elemento = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [self.elemento setObject:[TBXML textForElement:titolo] forKey:@"Titolo"];

            NSString *indirizzoImmagine = [TBXML textForElement:descrizione];
            NSRange rangeSRC = [indirizzoImmagine rangeOfString:@"src=\""];
            indirizzoImmagine = [indirizzoImmagine substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(rangeSRC)];
            NSRange rangeAMP = [indirizzoImmagine rangeOfString:@"&amp"];
            NSRange rangeWidth = [indirizzoImmagine rangeOfString:@"&width"];
            if (rangeAMP.location != NSNotFound) {
                indirizzoImmagine = [indirizzoImmagine substringToIndex:NSMaxRange(rangeAMP)];
            }
            else if (rangeWidth.location != NSNotFound){
                indirizzoImmagine = [indirizzoImmagine substringToIndex:NSMaxRange(rangeWidth)];
            }        
            indirizzoImmagine = [indirizzoImmagine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp" withString:@""];
            indirizzoImmagine = [indirizzoImmagine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&width" withString:@""];



            [self.elemento setObject:indirizzoImmagine forKey:@"IndirizzoImmagine"];

            [self.elemento setObject:[TBXML textForElement:descrizione] forKey:@"Descrizione"];
            [self.array addObject:self.elemento];
        }

    }
    while ((items=items->nextSibling));

}
```

then I start with download

```
- (void) loadURL:(NSURL *)url index:(int)index
{

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];


    ASIDownloadCache *cache = [[ASIDownloadCache alloc] init];

    [request setDownloadCache:cache];
    [request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
    [request setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];

    [cache setStoragePath:@"/Users/kikko/kikko/xxx"];

    request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:index], @"index",
                        url, @"url", nil];


    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}


    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {

        int index = [[request.userInfo valueForKey:@"index"] intValue];

    ASIDownloadCache *cache = [[ASIDownloadCache alloc] init];  
    [cache setStoragePath:@"/Users/kikko/kikko/xxx"];

    [request.userInfo valueForKey:@"url"];

    if ([cache cachedResponseDataForURL:[request.userInfo valueForKey:@"url"]]==nil) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[request.userInfo valueForKey:@"url"]);

        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        NSArray* rows = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
        [table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    }

    }

    - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {
        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);

    }
```

at the end I put the image inside cell.imageview

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.array.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}

-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)stringa {

    NSRange r;

    NSString *str = stringa;
    while ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    return str; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

elemento = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSURL *indirizzoImmagine = [NSURL URLWithString:[elemento objectForKey:@"IndirizzoImmagine"]];

[self loadURL:indirizzoImmagine index:indexPath.row];

ASIDownloadCache *cache = [[ASIDownloadCache alloc] init];
[cache setStoragePath:@"/Users/kikko/kikko/xxx"];

dataImmagine = [cache cachedResponseDataForURL:indirizzoImmagine];

[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataImmagine]];

cell.textLabel.text = [elemento objectForKey:@"Titolo"];

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to go about this, but the most minimally invasive way to your existing code is to attach a userinfo dictionary to your request object.

In your traverse method do this:

```
//...
while ((items=items->nextSibling));
for (int i = 0; i < [self.array count]; i++)
{
    [arrayData addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

Then do this in your request methods

```
- (void) loadURL:(NSURL *)url index:(int)index
{

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
    [request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
    [request setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];

    request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:index], @"index", nil];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    int index = [[request.userInfo valueForKey:@"index"] intValue];
    [arrayData replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:responseData];



    //EDIT below:
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
    NSArray* rows = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

In your cell code, do this:

```
if ([arrayData objecAtIndex:indexPath.row] != [NSNull null]) {
         UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         imageView.image = img;
         [cell.imageView setImage:img];        
    } else {

        imageView.image = nil;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much, I have also another question, in this way the for get image I have to scrol down and then scroll up, how can I reloaddata of table showing the image when it was downloaded?

Comment: Edited the answer.  In the requestFinished method you'll want to call reloadRowsAtIndexPath::

Comment: Depending on the size of your list you are going to have memory problems. Instead of storing your images in an array... you should call the loadUrl:index: method straight from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and use the reloadRowsAtIndexPath call when it comes back. You can skip adding it to arrayData altogether. Your caching the images so it should be pretty fast the second time around.

Comment: in fact I spent a lot of memory, :( I have around 200/300 item, I don't understand how can I do what you say? I have another question, the tables has 200/300 item but whe nI louch the table I display only 10/15 items, then I display e "load more..." if I put a table reloadData when I create and when I click on load more can be a good idea?

Comment: get rid of arrayData altogether and instead grab the image from the ASI download cached. There's a way to grab the image file straight from the cache.

Comment: I'm stupid...I use your method but inside cellForRowAtIndexPath I put an if that check if the data are cached, if yes take the data from cache else no run loadURL and download the image...seems to work!

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel this answered your question, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There is best example given by Apple to download and show images Asyn

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Meanwhile i will check your code as well